# SystemVerilog error with queue insert w/ another queue as argument

Tags: system-verilog, cadence

I have some queues declared like so:

```
static bit [127:0]   same_addr_mem_model [int][$]; 
static bit [127:0]   temp_addr_mem_model [int][$];
```

Then later on the line of code:

```
same_addr_mem_model[write_addr].insert(0,temp_addr_mem_model[write_addr]); // write_addr is some int
```

And that line gives me the compiler error with Cadence IES:

> assignment operator type check failed (expecting datatype compatible with 'packed array' but found 'queue of packed array [127:0] of bit' instead).

But as I've found documentation online it looks like a queue is a perfectly valid argument for `insert()`. Any idea what is wrong here? This code compiles and runs with Synopsys VCS, by the way.

Comment: Can you link to the online documentation mentioned?

Comment: Maybe documentation is the wrong word...it's an article. http://asicguru.com/system-verilog/tutorial/sv-arrays/4/

Answer (score 3):

The function prototype for `insert` is:

```
function void insert(input int index, input element_t item);
```

So if you are creating a queue of `ints` then you cannot add a queue of `ints` using `insert`.

It's not uncommon for vendors to not implement all of the language spec, or implement vendor-specific features that are not in the spec.  This is a case though where is seems VCS is just wrong for allowing this. I would double-check that it's actually doing what you expect.

Functions in SystemVerilog cannot be overloaded by argument type, so there would be no way to implement two `insert` functions, one taking the element type and the other taking a queue of elements.

You should be able to get the equivalent behavior using assignment syntax.

```
same_addr_mem_model[write_addr] = {temp_addr_mem_model[write_addr], same_addr_mem_model[write_addr]});
```

See section 7.10.4 of the 2012 SystemVerilog spec.

Comment: Ok that is interesting to know. In regards to the problem at hand, I assume logically the code is trying to insert the contents of temp_addr_mem_model[write_addr] into same_addr_mem_model[write_addr] at the front of the queue. Is there a method that can do this or do I need to do it one at a time?

Comment: I made the same assumption about your example code. My answer shows how to do the same with an assignment, e.g.  q1 = {q1, q2}.